# Facebook "apprequest" dialog asks for facebook login where as app is already logged it to facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, session, single-sign-on, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm following example of facebook authentication

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/authenticate/

for Login i've used:

```
 [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES 
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                      if (session.isOpen) 
                                      {
                                          appDelegate.session=session; 

                                      }
                                  }//end completionHandler
         ];
```

and for facebook apprequest dialog:

```
 if (nil == appDelegate.facebook) 
{
    appDelegate.facebook = [[Facebook alloc]
                            initWithAppId:FBSession.activeSession.appID
                            andDelegate:nil];

    // Store the Facebook session information
    appDelegate.facebook.accessToken = FBSession.activeSession.accessToken;
    appDelegate.facebook.expirationDate = FBSession.activeSession.expirationDate;
}

[self.facebook dialog:APPREQUEST
       andParams:params
     andDelegate:self];
```

after some time when i try to run app again then app is connected to facebook and FBSession is also active, but when i call apprequest dialog then it asks for login.

is there any problem with appDelegate.facebook = [[Facebook alloc]  or my session is expired?

Any suggestion please?

Comment: i've also added the line [self.facebook extendAccessTokenIfNeeded]; in "applicationDidBecomeActive" appDelegate method.

Comment: Where have you placed your if (nil == appDelegate.facebook)  ... code? Is it inside the session open completion handler?

Comment: Hi Abernathy! thanks for responding. I've placed this line after FBSession is opened with permissions but not exactly in completion handler, and also placed piece of code in AppDelegate didFinishLauching. i.e if the FBSession.activeSession.isOpen==YES then same chunk of code as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing your Facebook object session setting code inside the completion handler. The completion handler should be called whenever the session changes, for example, later on when the token is extended, it should be called again. That way you can keep the Facebook object session refreshed. You should not have to extend the access token yourself, the SDK now does that automatically for you.

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions 
                               allowLoginUI:YES 
                          completionHandler:
    ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        if (session.isOpen) 
        {
            appDelegate.session=session; 

            if (nil == appDelegate.facebook) 
            {
                appDelegate.facebook = [[Facebook alloc]
                        initWithAppId:FBSession.activeSession.appID
                        andDelegate:nil];
            }

            // Store the Facebook session information
            appDelegate.facebook.accessToken = FBSession.activeSession.accessToken;
            appDelegate.facebook.expirationDate = FBSession.activeSession.expirationDate;
        } // if session open
        else 
        {
            appDelegate.facebook = nil;
        } // session not open
    } //end completionHandler
];
```

Comment: Thank you C Abernathy! actually i was not managing session properly,
Can you please tell me that should i close the session in AppDelegate.m when app is being terminated or not?
i want to keep user logged in whenever he launch app, unless he logout manually.  i'm little bit confused between FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded and FBSessionStateOpen.

Comment: You can call [FBSession.activeSession close]; in the applicationWillTerminate: method. This just closes the session but does not clear the cache. As you wish, you can close the session and clear the cache when the user explicitly logs out. FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded means a cached token was found, at this stage the session is not open. If this session has open called then it will go into the FBSessionStateOpen without needing to show a login UI.